# Creating ZIP files on the fly from Amazon S3 using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, zip

I am creating a web application, with an online store, to purchase small digital files. When the user has added all the files they want to purchase, they pay and then should be presented with a ZIP download of their purchase.

The website/app is made in Node.js and uses Node raw (no Nginx or Apache for example). The files are stored on Amazon S3. The shopping cart and web app is all in-house, except for the necessary Node.js modules.

I'm looking for a solution where I can choose which files the user has ordered from Amazon S3, package them up as a ZIP file and give it to the user as a download.

I'm looking for a relatively simple solution if possible, does one exist?

Many thanks! James

Comment: This package seems to do exactly that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-zip